# Google App Engine: Exception while using TaskQueue with JUnit test cases

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit, task-queue

I want to call task queue from Junit Test cases. my code is:

```
@Test
    public void monthlyCronTest1() throws Exception {
....
       Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("updateVcoCron");
       TaskOptions options = TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl(String.format("/api/v1/users/update/validation/points")).method(TaskOptions.Method.GET);
                    options.param("pageNumber", String.valueOf(pageNumber));
                    options.param("validatableBrands", validatableBrands);
          queue.add(options); // this line throw exception
......
}
```

here I am getting error:

```
 Exception:java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified queue is unknown : updateVcoCron
    [junit] 1577867 INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory  - Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized f
rom default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
    [junit] 1577867 INFO  org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory  - Quartz scheduler version: UNKNOWN.UNKNOWN.UNKNOWN
    [junit] 1577867 INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler  - Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
```

2) If I use default Queue like:

```
   Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
```

I get different error.

```
    [junit] com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$ApplicationException: ApplicationError: 2: Received exception executing h
ttp method GET against URL http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/update/validation/points?pageNumber=1&validatableBrands=Vi
rgin+Trains: Connection to http://localhost:8080 refused
    [junit]     at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.dev.LocalURLFetchService.fetch(LocalURLFetchService.java:412)
    [junit]     at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.LocalTaskQueue$UrlFetchServiceLocalTaskQueueCallback.execute(L
ocalTaskQueue.java:701)
    [junit]     at com.google.appengine.api.taskqueue.dev.UrlFetchJob.execute(UrlFetchJob.java:90)
    [junit]     at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
    [junit]     at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
    [junit] 432275 ERROR org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger  - Job (default.task-1a8a7b8a-db49-432e-ac3d-cce784211b8a threw an
exception.
```

### My queue.xml is in the below path:

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF.

Now my question: is there any configuration left for JUnit environment? why it is not picking queue.xml? Please help here.

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing the "The specified queue is unknown" error. After looking at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/11200214/2742117, I fixed it by adding this to my base test class

```
private static String dir;
static {
  dir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/queue.xml";
  System.out.println(dir);
}

protected final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
  new LocalServiceTestHelper(
      //some other configurations removed for brevity...
      new LocalTaskQueueTestConfig().setQueueXmlPath(dir)
  );
```

After this my tests were able to work with my non default queue.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue not in my unit tests, but in actuality. In the end I had to actually add the new queue in my queue.xml

```
<queue>
    <name>myNewQueue</name>
    <rate>100/s</rate>
    <max-concurrent-requests>100</max-concurrent-requests>
    <retry-parameters>
        <task-age-limit>300h</task-age-limit>
        <min-backoff-seconds>10</min-backoff-seconds>
        <max-backoff-seconds>200</max-backoff-seconds>
        <max-doublings>0</max-doublings>
    </retry-parameters>
    <target>my-queue-service</target>
</queue>
```